# How do I handle multi-file projects with org-babel?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I'm trying to handle multiple files which have source blocks which depend on each other.

For example, I have a file *decorators.org* with some common Python decorators that I use frequently, and that I'd like to use on functions in other files in the same project.

I can think of a couple of ways to approach this, but I'm not sure which will actually work and which is the standard way of doing things:

- Execute `(org-babel-lob-ingest ./decorators.org)`, either in an emacs-lisp block or on loading the file. But then I'm not sure how to access that variable after it's been injested.
- Use `org-babel-load-file`, but it looks like that only works with emacs-lisp source blocks
- Force the files I depend on to be pre-tangled by calling `org-babel-tangle-file`, and them import them using normal Python import statements.

Is one of these a good approach, or is there some better way to do this that I've missed?

Comment: Trying to do something similar in Python. see emacs exchange [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/40671/17548), My answer was either tangling the src block into a .py file and call it in Python when needed, or use `:session`, only that all the src blocks need be evaluated in the same Python session. The `#+CALL` option in  [other answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/40717/17548) to that question, I can't get right, the doc is minimal, I tried all combinations of arguments for parsing in order to get a class or a function to be recognized in the new namespace with no success.. you?

Comment: Thanks, the answers to that question look helpful. I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: So, far, no luck with #+CALL. This is what I've tried: https://hastebin.com/omixikebah.hs

I've asked for help in the IRC channel on Freenode for now.